# Unsure how to work with a function, must follow specific guidelines

Tags: c++, function, average

I am extremely confused. I have to follow these specific guidelines:

Make a program that will compute and output the average of 10 exam scores, entered by the user. Finish the function, so that the main will work correctly.  Feel free to modify the main as you please as well. 
I do not believe we need to change the main and do not believe we should use 10 variables. Here is the code I must add to, I believe the main is finished. Your help is very appreciated!!!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 NOT ADD CODE HERE!!!   
float calculateAverageTestScore(int amountOfScores);

int main(void) 
{
  const int NUMBER_OF_SCORES = 10;

  cout << "The average test score was: " << calculateAverageTestScore(NUMBER_OF_SCORES) << endl;

  return 0;
}



//INPUT: an amount of test scores 
//OUTPUT: the average of these scores 
//This function will obtain amountOfScores test scores from the user, and return
//their average - to be used elsewhere.
float calculateAverageTestScore(int amountOfScores)
{
  float average;

  //add code here 



   return average;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have 10 variables for it. Just use array to store 10 scores then using for loop, compute their average.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `<string>` library?

Comment: You can always just add them up as you go and divide by the number at the end.

Comment: @BlitzNinja29 How exactly could I code that? I'm really new to coding.

Comment: @BradyDean I have heard of it but am probably more familiar with an array.

Comment: @BradyDean Thank you sooooo much, it worked I'll definitely be studying that!

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

float calculateAverageTestScore(int amountOfScores);

int main() {
  const int NUMBER_OF_SCORES = 10;
  const float score = calculateAverageTestScore(NUMBER_OF_SCORES);
  std::cout << "The average test score was: " << score << '\n';
}

float calculateAverageTestScore(int amountOfScores) {
  float sum = 0;

  std::string buffer;
  for (int i = 0; i < amountOfScores; ++i) {
    std::cout << "score #" << i + 1 << ": ";
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    sum += std::stof(buffer); // TODO: Error handling
  }

  return sum / amountOfScores;
}
```

Comment: May you never have to work beside and have to perform the duties of someone who cut and pasted their way through school.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand what you're getting at but we were all beginners at some point. I would rather expose someone to a good solution than let them sift through the "beginners guide" shit on Google.

Comment: With you on that bit. You can't expect anyone to pick a good tutorial out of the much more common bad tutorial until they understand enough of the language to recognize a good tutorial. I just wish you could have found a way to describe the process instead of handing them an easily cut-n-pastable block. You can at least dodge the code-only answer by adding some explanation of what you're doing and why.

Comment: Although I agree with you 100% Brady Dean , user4581301 has a point too, the temptation of cut and paste is usually greater than actually learning this.